# Using IO::Select on STDIN on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, select

When I run the code below on a Linux system, as expected it outputs `Nothing is ready` about every two seconds, and also outputs anything entered on to console.

But on Windows, `can_read` returns instantly with zero items.

```
use IO::Select;

my $sel = IO::Select->new();
$sel->add(\*STDIN);

while ( 1 ) {

    my @ready = $sel->can_read(2);

    if ( scalar @ready == 0 ) {
        print "Nothing is ready\n";
    }

    foreach my $fh ( @ready ) {

        if ( $fh eq \*STDIN ) {
            my $in = <STDIN>;
            print "got $in from stdin\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that `select` works only on Windows sockets and not on STDIN. How can I use `IO::Select` on STDIN on a Windows system?

Comment: If this part of a larger application where STDIN is a pipe from a parent, you could fix this by using a socket instead of a pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, `perldoc perlport` states:

```
select  Only implemented on sockets. (Win32, VMS)
```

This is caused by Windows itself implementing `select()` only  for  sockets,  see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select.

The Windows equivalent seems to be [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/FileIO/i-o-completion-ports). But you have to find a way to use them from Perl.

If you really just care about STDIN, you can poll in a loop with `Term::ReadKey`  with a `ReadMode` of -1 (non-blocking). As the name of the module suggests, this   may only work on a tty.

If you start the Perl process yourself, you can use a `socketpair()` emulation (but one that uses the Windows function `WSASocket()`) and use that as the process's standard input.  I have described that in great detail at http://www.guido-flohr.net/platform-independent-asynchronous-child-process-ipc/.